# eval hiding code in JGraph vs obfuscation\packing

Tags: javascript, eval

Almost every time when there is a question about eval, the answer is the same - do not use eval. I think that there is a reason eval to exist. But there are manny gaps to fall.

So about jgraph - why they use eval(in this [example](http://www.jgraph.com/demo/mxgraph/orgchart.html)); is it practical to use eval to hide code, when there is obfuscation and packing tools for javascript? Is this the only "practical" use?

There are a lot of money involved there, so I think they know what they are doing.

Answer (score 1):

> There are a lot of money involved there, so I think they know what they are doing.

Not really.  It's a pointless measure designed to slow down any potential plagiarism from JS developers but in reality it adds, at most, 30 seconds to the steps necessary to attain the de-obfuscated code.  For instance, consider what happens if I open http://jsFiddle.net or http://jsbin.com and type the following into the JavaScript box:

```
var txt = "textContent" in document.body ? "textContent" : "innerText",
    eval = function (s) { document.body[txt] = s; }
```

Then, I copy and paste the code from that site directly below this in the fiddle and hit run.  The result is, all the code is dumped onto the page so that I can copy and paste it into http://jsbeautifier.org.  And that isn't the only way to dump the code.  One could just copy and paste the string into any developer tools console window and get the result.

Obfuscation is one thing, but adding an extra layer using `eval` is, in my opinion, amateurish, clutching at straws and showing desperation to hide their precious source code.  It doesn't at all show that they know what they're doing.

Answer (score -1):

You CAN use eval! It gives you much more possibilities!
Sometimes there is no other way to do something.

But:

- code executed through eval is maybe
  slower
- errors in evaled codes are really
  hard to find (you don´t get line
  numbers or something)
- eval could make your code unreadable if used to often

Example that would be impossible without eval:

```
var varname = "X";
var varvalue = 5;
eval("var "+varname+" = "+varvalue+";");
console.log(X);
```

Comment: "Sometimes there is no other way to do something." <- False statement. The only things you need eval for in JavaScript is things you _should not_ be doing in JavaScript. `eval` is an academic toy.

Comment: @Raynos: It´s rare but true ;) For example dynamically defining a "var" is not possible without eval.

Comment: @FlashFan: I am eager to see a concrete example.

Comment: @FlashFan `window[varname] = varvalue` dynamic global variable. `obj[varname] = varvalue` dynamic hash. You should not need dynamic local variables. that's just bad code.

Comment: @Raynos for the most cases, you are definitely right! But sometimes you need it as a trick. It´s hard to explain such situations ;)

Comment: @FlashFan sometimes you need it as a _hack_. I can understand that. Your allowed to hack your code with eval because doing it without requires too much refactoring or would take too long.

Comment: @FlashFan: there are very few practical uses for `eval` that cannot be done better without `eval`.  The only time I've ever needed it is to provide a console window to a web page environment that didn't have developer tools.